# Email template not opening on IOS devices

Tags: ios, opencart, email-templates

We have a online store and we are trying to design our email templates that the customer receives, order confirmation, user registration and so on. But i have a problem with opening the email on IOS devices. The message i get when i open the mail on my iPhone/iPad is "This message has no content". I think this have to do with the email template. We use opencart as a platform with the "Email Template" extension.

You can see the code below:
http://pastebin.com/p4Hj7VZz

Is there anything obvious wrong with the code that i wrote?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not an OpenCart issue. Your code first of all is hideous. I would reduce it to pure minimal clean coded HTML5. Aside from this use more tables to avoid white spaces.. and what Jay said below.. see html5boilerplate on SO

Answer (score 1):

I kept having the same error as you, but not always. Sometimes the mail would just not display in iOS for no logical reason. I think the problem must persist in the "mail" library. I switched to PHPMailer and now emails always work in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your iOS device is either not accepting HTML emails or the email you're sending is malformed and can't be read by your email client